# Earth Engine: Unable to process images from August or September

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am unable to load and process images from August or September. I have tried with MODIS and Sentinel 2. Quite strange. Here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c13e5185ed18859ab47cb9a4fffb98ac) to the code, also included below.

```
var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

var s2f_07 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(07,07,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_07M = s2f_07.mean();

var s2f_08 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(08,08,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_08M = s2f_08.mean();

var s2f_09 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(09,09,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_09M = s2f_09.mean();
```

Comment: Not sure why, but in the cases of Aug and Sept, the code works if you use `ee.Filter.calendarRange(8,8,'month')` instead of `ee.Filter.calendarRange(08,08,'month')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading 0 makes the numbers unrecognizable. Remove the 0s. Putting 0 before a number makes it into an octal number literal. Octal numbers have a range of 8 digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). 08, 09, etc are thus not recognized.

Here is a proof: https://code.earthengine.google.com/66be7f0b065500947c1eda7e0d5277ce

Comment: This doesn't explain why the given code works with `calendarRange(07,07,'month')` and not `calendarRange(08,08 ,'month')`.

Comment: and it works fine for other months... e.g. (calendarRange(06,06,'month)...?

Comment: @JeponNomad - Putting 0 before a number makes it into an octal number literal. Octal numbers have a range of 8 digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). 08, 09, etc are thus not recognized.

Comment: @davidguerena - I have edited the answer to include the reason it does not work. If the answer satisfies your question, please accept it so that it can be removed from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Thanks! Solved the issue