# No Images found for the month of June in Sentinel-2 using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to collect images using Sentinel-2 for the month of June, but it says no image was found.

Here is the code snippet

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

Map.centerObject(thane,12)  //ROI

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B8']
 
var filtered = s2
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-06-01', '2018-06-30'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(thane))
  .select(bands)
```

Here is the error

```
Image (Error)
Image.sampleRegions: Invalid numInputs: 0.
```

I checked this previously asked question on [stackoverflow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340406/earth-engine-unable-to-process-images-from-august-or-september). So I believe it is the issue with the month number. But when I changed it to '6' instead of '06', the issue remained.

How can I resolve this?
Please find the code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1e8003e4babe6a26c80d7414920ff0e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [dataset catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR) for that collection:

> The Sentinel-2 L2 data are downloaded from scihub. They were computed by running sen2cor. WARNING: ESA did not produce L2 data for all L1 assets, and earlier L2 coverage is not global.

You will have to fallback to the `"COPERNICUS/S2` or `COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED` collections, which unfortunately are not surface reflectance.